# Where to find documentation about AMP script extension versions: module/nomodule .js/.mjs?

Tags: amp-html

[The spec for extended components](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/?format=websites#extended-components) says that:

> The script URL must start with https://cdn.ampproject.org and must follow a very strict pattern of /v\d+/[a-z-]+-(latest|\d+|\d+.\d+).js.

I have noticed that some websites are using .mjs version vs .js version like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.mjs" async="" custom-element="amp-ad" type="module" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I'm not sure where can I read more about .mjs version specs.

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking at code generated by the amp-optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction. I have found this https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/266c274e2aa669399dede55e9fc55b8917069279/validator/validator-main.protoascii#L3453 and it seems the documentation is still not ready, but it gives me the idea